# Solution for a particular nonlinear wave equation (in 2D)

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, wave-equation

I'm tryng to solve the following:
\begin{equation}
u_{tt}(t,x)-u_{xx}(t,x)=K\cdot\text{Exp}\left (u(t,x)\right)
\end{equation}
with $K \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. For now I don't care about boundaries conditions, then you can set them as you want.

Comment: What did you try to solve it? Did you take a look at particular cases when $u$ does not depend on $t$ or $x$? Did you try the characteristics method?

Comment: this some sort of sine gordon equation

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I solved the two particular cases ($x$-independent and $t$-independent) and I get the following expression (for $t$):

$$
\log\left [ \frac{\frac{1}{2}c_1 \text{sech}^2[\sqrt{c_1(t+c_2)^2}]}{2 \cdot K} \right ]
$$
My attempt is to classify 2D spacetime metric using the following claim: every two-dimensional Lorentz manifold is conformally flat.

Comment: @tired I've already brooded  about gordon equation, but it seems a little more complicated!

Comment: If I remember correctly, the case of $t$-independent solutions also has a logarithm involved. Maybe the change of variables $u = \ln v$ could lead to something. The equation would look like $v(v_{tt}-v_{xx}) = Kv^3 + v_t^2+v_x^2$.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Yes! There is a logarithm as more external function in the solution: $\log[\dots]$. There is something similar also for $x$-independent solution. The change of variable proposed is the inverse which I've done to get the first equation. Actually I started from:
$$
K=\frac{-\left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\Omega(x,t) \right )^2+\left ( \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\Omega(x,t) \right )^2+\Omega(x,t) \left [ \left ( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\Omega(x,t) \right )-\left ( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\Omega(x,t) \right )\right ]}{\left ( \Omega(x,t) \right)^3}.
$$

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake with sign at $v_t^2$. Anyway, I don't see an immediate way to solve this equation...

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Nevermind, thank you for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact this belongs to a PDE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/npde/npde2103.pdf.

The general solution is $u(t,x)=f(x-t)+g(x+t)-2\ln\left(n\int^{x-t}e^{f(r)}~dr-\dfrac{K}{8n}\int^{x+t}e^{g(s)}~ds\right)~.$

Comment: Thank you! It seems quite right.